# Qt UI testing : Can't perform QTest::keyPress

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, qtestlib

I have class `MyForm` which inherited from `QMainWindow`.

Here's my code:

```
std::auto_ptr<MyForm> pForm(new MyForm(3,3));
QTest::keyPress(&pForm, Qt::Key_0);
```

However when I use `QTest::keyPress` on it, I'm getting:

> error: no matching function for call to keyPress(std::auto_ptr*, Qt::Key)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
QTest::keyPress(pForm.get(), Qt::Key_0);
```

The first argument should have type `QWidget*`, not `std::auto_ptr<MyForm>*`.